# Can a neutered Jack Russell and a intact husky live in the same household

Tags: dogs

I have a neutered Jack Russell My grandson wants to come to live he has an intact Husky can these two fur babies live in the same household?

Answer (score 3):

This is going to depend on so many more factors than breed and being neutered or not.

Ultimately, you have to either know or find out how your dog reacts to other dogs in “his”territory, how both are with other dogs in general and finally, just like with humans, whether those two individuals get along or not.

If you can predict problems based on the first two points, I’d recommend you experiment *carefully*, simply because the size difference can, in case of a serious escalation, be very dangerous for the smaller dog - that the average Jack Russel is tenacious and slightly megalomaniac doesn’t help.

On the other hand, it’s always an individual case, dog A and dog B with their specific characters and quirks. When you bring them together, plan for management in the first phase, just to be sure. If you are not familiar with the topic, I very much recommend you learn about the subtle ways dog communicate, their body language etc. This will help you read and understand what’s happening between the two and recognize potential escalations early on.